# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when using render

Tags: node.js

I was trying to get the hbs file after logging in as a new page

This is my login

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
var username = request.body.username;
var password = request.body.password;
if (username && password) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            request.session.loggedin = true;
            request.session.username = username;
            response.redirect('/home');
        } else {
            response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');

        }           
        response.end();
    });
} else {
    response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
    response.end();
}
});
```

This is my function if authorized

```
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
if (request.session.loggedin) {
    //here is getting an error
    response.render('home');
} else {
    response.send('Please login to view this page!');
}
response.end();
});
```

Error message

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

My directories

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isNA5.png)

Comment: Remove the `response.end()` from all your handlers.  `response.redirect()` and `response.send()` already complete the response.  No need to call `response.end()` after them.  Only things like `response.write()` which can be called multiple times needs a `.end()`.  I don't know if that is causing your issue or not, but it's worth fixing to see.

Comment: Wow that works really well,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `response.end()` from all your handlers.

Both `response.redirect()` and `response.send()` already complete the response. No need to call `response.end()` after them.

Only things like `response.write()` which can be called multiple times and does not complete the response on its own needs a `.end()`.